# Modal popup extender not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have two modal popup extenders on the page

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupConfirm" runat="server"
                        TargetControlID="Button4"
                        PopupControlID="pnlPopup"
                        BackgroundCssClass="ModalPoopup"
                        BehaviorID="popup" />

<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
                        TargetControlID="anchorbtn"
                        X="200" RepositionMode="None"
                        PopupDragHandleControlID="EmptyPanel"
                        PopupControlID="pnlSelfOrLetOut"
                        BackgroundCssClass="ModalPoopup"
                        BehaviorID="popupSL" />
```

and I am calling first modal popup extender in c# like

```
ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
```

modal popup is not showing on that.

Please help me.

Comment: Please post all relevant information (say  anchorbtn,EmptyPanel,pnlSelfOrLetOut,ModalPoopup css ,popupSL ) and cs code from where `ModalPopupExtender1.Show();` is calling...

Comment: Have you debuged this Show() call?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidForModel" runat="server" /> 

<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupConfirm" runat="server" TargetControlID="hidForModel"
PopupControlID="pnlPopup" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPoopup" BehaviorID="popup">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks for solution but I have already used the script manager on the page.Give another solution.

Comment: add a hidden field to your page. make the ModalPopup TargetControlID as hiddenfield ID